# Capistrano fails compiling assets (or right after)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-deployment, capistrano

Whenever I try to deploy I get to `deploy:assets:precompile` and then things stop right at the "compiling..." step:

```
  INFO [2a7f255a] Finished in 16.140 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [26fcfc4a] Running if test ! -d /srv/ciao/releases/20210123210203; then echo "Directory does not exist '/srv/ciao/releases/20210123210203'" 1>&2; false; fi as ubuntu@178.128.237.226
 DEBUG [26fcfc4a] Command: if test ! -d /srv/ciao/releases/20210123210203; then echo "Directory does not exist '/srv/ciao/releases/20210123210203'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [26fcfc4a] Finished in 0.240 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [da415407] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile as ubuntu@178.128.237.226
 DEBUG [da415407] Command: cd /srv/ciao/releases/20210123210203 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.0" RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
 DEBUG [da415407]   yarn install v1.22.5
 DEBUG [da415407]   [1/4] Resolving packages...
 DEBUG [da415407]   success Already up-to-date.
 DEBUG [da415407]   Done in 1.15s.
 DEBUG [da415407]   yarn install v1.22.5
 DEBUG [da415407]   [1/4] Resolving packages...
 DEBUG [da415407]   [2/4] Fetching packages...
 DEBUG [da415407]   info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
 DEBUG [da415407]   info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
 DEBUG [da415407]   info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
 DEBUG [da415407]   info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
 DEBUG [da415407]   [3/4] Linking dependencies...
 DEBUG [da415407]   warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
 DEBUG [da415407]   warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
 DEBUG [da415407]   warning " > webpacker-svelte@0.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "svelte@>= 3".
 DEBUG [da415407]   [4/4] Building fresh packages...
 DEBUG [da415407]   Done in 6.89s.
 DEBUG [da415407]   Compiling...
 DEBUG [da415407]   Compilation failed:
```

I'm able to run `rake assets:precompile` locally with no issues.

Comment: Have you tried running `rake assets:precompile` in a production environment? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, maybe it shows something different. If it still succeeds locally, I would ssh into the server and try to run the command there, maybe you have a better error doing that.

Comment: That seems to help.  Also running `bundle exec cap production deploy` rather than `cap production deploy` although I'm not sure if that really matters.

Comment: Pudiste resolver, ¿como?